# Average values of imaginary numbers using integrals, is this result valid or does it even make any sense ??

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

**Computing average values of complex numbers from a to b**

I'm not sure whether we can talk about average values of imaginary numbers using integrals or not. I thought what would be the average value of $e^x$ from $-i$ to $i$. We know that average value of a function from $a$ to $b$ is:

$\frac{\int_a^bf(x)dx}{b - a}$

And if we let $f(x)$ be $e^x$ and $a = -i,b = i$

We might write the average value of the e^x from $-i$ to $ias following:

$avg=\frac{\int_{-i}^{+i}e^xdx}{i - (-i)}= \frac{1}{2i}[e^x]^{+i}_{-i}=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{i}-e^{-i})=\frac{e^i-e^{-i}}{2i} = sin(1)$

I thought it is pretty interesting to find result $sin(1)$ but the real question is:

1) Does this integral even make any sense? What happens if we try to integrate between two imaginary numbers ?

2) Is the average value of complex numbers defined? If so, is it still the same as real numbers ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I don't have time to write up a full answer right now, but I'd encourage you to Google "complex contour integration" and see what you find.